# Bigrams frequency in str and dict comprehensions

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get dictionary with 'bigram: frequency' where bigram = str[i] + str[i + 1]. So this is my solution:

f_dict = {}

```
for i in range(0, len(string) - 1, step):
    if string[i] + string[i + 1] in f_dict:
        f_dict[string[i] + string[i + 1]] += 1
    else:
        f_dict[string[i] + string[i + 1]] = 1
```

Is it possible to write this with dict comprehensions in one line, or is there a better solution (within the meaning of performance)?

Comment: Can you post an example of `string`?  You are aware that `len()` returns the number of *characters* of a string, not the number of *words* right? Similarly, `string[i]` will return the ith character.

Comment: @Chris Mueller, for example: string = 'abcdefghijk'. In my case bigram - is a substring of two characters from text, for example 'ab', 'bc'. Acording to the step I consider cross and non-cross bigrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows :

```
s = 'abaabaab' # Your string
# Dictionary comprehension
dic = {k : s.count(k) for k in {s[i]+s[i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1)}}
```

Result :

```
In[2]: dic
Out[3]: {'aa': 2, 'ab': 3, 'ba': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought dict comp would work faster but it works slower than my solution. For my text: your method: 0.01200 sec, my: 0.00900 sec (in average).